# Identifying recon in web

Tags: web-application, threat-modeling, mod-security

I recently deployed mod_security module in my Apache Web Server. I know the OWASP CRS rules include tags to categorize attacks but I want to make higher level categories, particularly to identify recon from the generated logs.

Having said that, I want to know if my understanding is correct on the following points:

1. Any HTTP method that is not supported by the application is a scanning/recon attempt. Protocol Anomalies/Missing Headers and the likes also fall in the same category.
2. Given that the Apache directive `ProxyRequests` is set to Off, any CONNECT attempts will also lie in scanning/recon. It can not be categorized as Proxy Abuse if the server doesn't entertain proxy requests, right?
3. The OPTIONS method, from my understanding as well as from what the spec says, sounds like it's made for scanning the methods available. Nmap and other tools of the ilk shoot off OPTIONS requests to find out what the server has to offer. But should I indiscriminately put all the OPTIONS requests under scanning attempts?
4. How to distinguish legitimate GET requests from malicious ones? And by malicious, I mean ones that are a precursor to an attack? Of course I can correlate all the logs to find links but is there an immediate way? By the user agent? What if the user agent cannot be identified?

I apologize for bombarding all the questions simultaneously, but I didn't think it would be a good idea to ask them separately. Rookie mistake, maybe.